# dbms_out returning column 1: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Running this query in sql-developer :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  ('schema > table > key ');
SELECT  'table_name' TABLE_NAME , t.* FROM table_name  t    ;

END ;
```

I get this message :

```
 Error report -
 ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in
 this SELECT statement
 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
 *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
 *Action:
```

while when I run the two statements one by one it works fine.
so why do I get the error and how to avoid it ?

many thanks,

Comment: You have to use `INTO` clause in plsql to store fetched values by select

Comment: `PL/SQL` is not a scripting language.. and it is different from `SQL`. When you run a query in `PL/SQL`, you cannot expect it to print the results in your console just like that. Like with JDBC, you have to feed those data into a `PL/SQL` variable, and then print it using the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package. When you ran the PL/SQL without the SELECT, it worked because,it didn't have any SQLs embedded.. Also, when you run a SQL separately, your `IDE ` will not execute it as `PL/SQL` but as a `SQL` only. Finally, you tried to merge them, and now SQL inside PL/SQL has to be handled like I mentioned before

Comment: Also worth noting that the line number for a PL/SQL error (PLS-00428 in this case) refers to the line within the PL/SQL code, not the whole script as you might be used to from running plain SQL in the worksheet. So counting from the start of the block at `BEGIN`, line 4 is the `select`, not the `dbms_output`. That seems to have confused you in the title, at least. (And it's even more confusing in trigger creation statements).

Comment: OK now I understand why SQL and PL/SQL are different; ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing SQL and PL/SQL statements, as explained in comments. You can select into something, but you'd either get a single row of data, or select into a collection and then iterate over that manually, as Aramillo showed.

You can use a ['cursor for-loop'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm) to iterate over your rows instead:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('schema > table > key ');
  FOR rec IN (SELECT 'table_name' TABLE_NAME , t.* FROM table_name t)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (rec.COLUMN_NAME1||','||rec.COLUMN_NAME2);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

But given your starting point it's simpler to leave the query as plan SQL and run it after the block:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('schema > table > key ');
END;
/
SELECT 'table_name' TABLE_NAME , t.* FROM table_name  t;
```

or in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, use the client [`prompt` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm) instead of `dbms_output`:

```
prompt schema > table > key
SELECT 'table_name' TABLE_NAME , t.* FROM table_name  t;
```

Answer (score 3):

For example, if you want to print columns `COLUMN_NAME` of your table, you can do somthing like this:

```
DECLARE
TYPE TABLE_OBJ IS TABLE OF TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
TABLE_T TABLE_OBJ;
BEGIN
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO TABLE_T FROM TABLE_NAME;

FOR i IN 1..TABLE_T.COUNT LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_T(i).COLUMN_NAME1||','||TABLE_T(i).COLUMN_NAME2);
END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: OK I added the index there

Comment: this is the error report I get now:    Error report -
ORA-06550: line 7, column 17:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
ORA-06550: line 7, column 25:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 7, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: DECLARE
TYPE TABLE_OBJ IS TABLE OF ALL_TABLES%ROWTYPE;
TABLE_T TABLE_OBJ;
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO TABLE_T FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE ROWNUM <= 10 ;

FOR i IN 1..TABLE_T.COUNT LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_T(i).OWNER||','||TABLE_T(i).TABLE_NAME);
END LOOP;

END;

Comment: @user3752281 - right, you'd need to modify that to `SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO ...` to use a PL/SQL collection. ([Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABEIACI))

Comment: DECLARE
TYPE TABLE_OBJ IS TABLE OF ALL_TABLES%ROWTYPE;
TABLE_T TABLE_OBJ;
BEGIN
SELECT X.* BULK COLLECT INTO TABLE_T FROM ALL_TABLES X WHERE ROWNUM <= 10 ;

FOR i IN 1..TABLE_T.COUNT LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_T(i).OWNER||','||TABLE_T(i).TABLE_NAME);
END LOOP;

END;

Comment: @user3752281 - you don't need to show your final code; I've added the missing bit to the answer. If this is working you can probably delete all the comments as they are not relevant any more. (And don't forget to upvote/accept this answer, of course!)